# retrieve mail info from an imap server

Tags: railo

I want to retrieve some e-mail informations from a Imap mail server.

I'm using Railo application server (not coldfusion).

After defining attributes values (serverURL,login and pswd) , I used the following instruction to open a connection:

```
<cfimap server = "#serverURL#"  username = "#login#" action="open"  password = "#pswd#" port='993'>
```

Unfotunately, it generates the following error:

```
Connection timed out: connect;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Comment: The most likely cause for a connection timeout is probably not within Railo itself. The most likely cause is a network issue. Have you verified that you can telnet from the machine that Railo is installed on to the IMAP port of the machine you're attempting to connect to?
How to test an IMAP connection using Telnet:
http://www.anta.net/misc/telnet-troubleshooting/imap.shtml

Answer (score 0):

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

As it says, connection timed out. Make sure that the url and ports are correct and, if the imap server is self hosted, to open port 993 as in the example on the imap server.

Answer (score 0):

Also be aware that depending on how you authenticate / connect changes the default port that is used with IMAP.

The default ports for IMAP are:

Standard Port:143 
Secure IMAP (IMAP4-SSL) Port:585
IMAP4 over SSL (IMAPS) Port:993

A easy way to test the credentials is to first connect a desktop mail client like Thunderbird or Apple Mail first. Then use those settings on the CFML Server.

Also sometimes the username requires the domain so even if the username is "john" you may have to authenticate with "john@yourdomain.com".